# building from source: incremental package download and build

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to build ROS-mobile on the Pandaboard.

Since I'm (obviously) facing errors, I find it would be best if I could incrementally download packages.

For example start with ros-base, build and install, then move to robot, then mobile.
Each time elimination the unneeded sources so to speed up the process.

How would I do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53005/building-from-source:-incremental-package-download-and-build/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2013-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you trying to install groovy? If yes, try the following:

clone the packages you want to install into the src folder. Try to build and install it and fix occurring errors. If catkin_make install worked on all the packages in the src folder, simply move all folders from the src folder to the base folder by typing

```
mkdir donotbuild
mv src/* donotbuild
```

now you can download the next package and try to build those.

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-01-23**:
Instead of moving the packages to a different location you should just create another workspace which builds on top of the first one (see http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying).

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-01-23**:
why? This is a lot harder! He will have to build up a chain of catkin workspaces which can become really confusing depending on how many iterations he is going for. If you read the tutorial, it becomes pretty clear, that you should not use it for a task like his. The tutorial states:

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-01-23**:
Other than that, novice users should have little reason to use this feature, and work with just one workspace to avoid confusion. Having a chain of workspaces also forces the user to call make in workspaces in the right order, and can cause failures if overlaying packages [...]